# A basic problem on convergence of random series

Tags: probability-theory

If $X_1, X_2, \dots$ are i.i.d and if $P(X_1 \geq 0) = 1$ and $P(X_1 > 0) > 0$ then prove that $\sum_{n}X_n = \infty$ with probability $1$.

I have to prove it by finding a positive $\epsilon$ such that $X_n > \epsilon$ infinitely often w.p. $1$.

I am able to prove the following by contradiction :

$P(X_n < 0   \text{    eventually}) > 0$, but that does not say that for some $n$,  $P(X_n <0) > 0$. How to proceed from here ?

Comment: do not forget that $X\ge 0$ as...

Comment: @mookid: true. But, how is that helping here from where I am stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $P(X_1>0)$, $\exists \epsilon >0$ such that $P(X>\epsilon)>0$. To see this, note that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n = \{X_1 >0\}$ where $A_n:= \{X_1 > \frac{1}{n}\}$. If all the sets $A_n$ were null, then the event $\{X_1 >0\}$ would be null (a contradiction - you are assuming this event has probability 1!).  Let $n_{*}$ denote some natural number with the property that $P(X_1 > \frac{1}{n_*}) > 0$, which exists by the argument above. Now just pick any $\epsilon \in (0, \frac{1}{n_*})$.

Then clearly $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(X_n> \epsilon) = \infty$, so by the Borel-Cantelli lemma, the event $\{X_n > \epsilon \quad \textrm{infinitely often}\} $ has probability 1. But

$$\{X_n > \epsilon \quad \textrm{infinitely often}\} \subseteq \{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n = \infty\} , $$

because all the random variables are nonnegative. The latter set thus also has probability 1. $\quad \square$